# D365 CRM how to access sub-grid cells DOM using queryselectorall()

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, dynamics-crm, queryselector

I need this functionality for my client, am am ferly new to CRM customization and i mostly do backend so plugins custom actions and custom apis. All 3 of this codes below always return null. What am i doing wrong.

```
function myGridClickHandler(executionContext) {

let formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 
let gridContext = formContext.getControl("Document_Barcodes2"); 
let grid = gridContext.getGrid();
let myContactsGridOnloadFunction = function() {
    console.log("Document_Barcodes2 Subgrid OnLoad event occurred");

  
   let elements = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll("div.ag-cell"); 
   let elements2 = document.querySelectorAll("div.ag-cell"); 
   let elements3=document.querySelectorAll('.ag-cell[col-id="ct_preview"]');
     debugger;  
    
    }
  gridContext.addOnLoad(myContactsGridOnloadFunction);



         
}
```

[The page and subgrid, it's the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJPbZ.png)

[The id,class... of the element i need to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlTLs.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: you should retrieve the records using the API, accessing directly the DOM is unsupported in Dynamics 365 CE